# How to change Symfony's Console Working Directory from a Command?

Tags: php, console-application, symfony-console

How can I change the `working directory` from within a `Symfony Console Application`?

For instance:

```
/var/www/path/to/something@MyMacBook$ symfonyapp go:root
Success
/var/www@MyMacBook$
```

Comment: Wont work that way. You try to change the working directory from the current comand line that you are working on, `symfonyapp` will open its on process and shell (check with `ps -af`). It is possible to do that with BASH, but i dont thing you can do this with `symfonyapp`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9168022/1220930